# How to detect a link to another section on the same page on an Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, href

I know how to detect a user tap on a link inside a `WebView`:

```
binding.webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
     override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
         println("shouldOverrideUrlLoading: ${request?.url?.toString()}")
         //do whatever and return false if we don't want the link to be launched
         return false
     }
 }
```

but this is not working for links to the same page, for example:

```
<a href="#tabpanel-size-guide-1">
   Size guide
</a>
```

I guess this is because links to same page are not loading a new url, and then this event `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not triggered.

So, my question is: Are there a way to detect user taps on this kind of links?

Comment: Try using shouldInterceptRequest instead, you are right about shouldOverrideUrlLoading, it won't trigger on the same domain.

Comment: Thanks @javdromero, unfortunately I've already tried it and it doesn't work. It's intercepting calls to get other resources, like favicon.